# Get a nullable datetime from django and convert it in golang

Tags: django, go

Here is the date that i send (in raw text) mode from a jsonified models.DateTimeField :

> 2019-05-07 16:49:47.351628+00:00

How i receive it in golang :

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/http"

    "github.com/lib/pq"
)
type DataLink struct {
    Created     pq.NullTime `json:"created"`
}

type SendData struct {
    Name string `json:"Name"`
}

func main() {

    var reception = DataLink{}
    var sendData = SendData{}
    sendData.Name = "Melon"
    url := "http://127.0.0.1:8309/getLinks/"
    fmt.Println("URL:>", url)

    js, err := json.Marshal(sendData)

    req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", url, bytes.NewBuffer(js))
    req.Header.Set("X-Custom-Header", "myvalue")
    req.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/json")

    client := &http.Client{}
    resp, err := client.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()

    //fmt.Println("response Status:", resp.Status)
    //fmt.Println("response Headers:", resp.Header)
    body, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    //fmt.Println("response Body:", string(body))
    err = json.Unmarshal(body, &reception)
    fmt.Println(reception.Created)
}
```

But when i print my object i have a :

```
{0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC false}
```

How to convert ideally from a django time field or with string manipulation my date time to make it compatible with go and pq.NullTime ?

Everything else works (bool, int, float , string) but not the date ...

Comment: https://play.golang.com/p/KC1yDeqkWFe

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a custom time type in order to `unmarshal` custom time format:

```
type Datetime struct {
    pq.NullTime
}

func (t *Datetime) UnmarshalJSON(input []byte) error {
    strInput := strings.Trim(string(input), `"`)
    newTime, err := time.Parse(time.RFC3339, strInput)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    t.pqNullTime = newTime
    return nil
}
```

By default json unmarshal expects date in the `RFC3339` format.

Comment: it doesn't work :/  .\DijkstraGreat.go:53:15: cannot use newTime (type time.Time) as type pq.NullTime in assignment

Comment: Why `pq.NullTime` you could use `time.Time`

Comment: @M14 How is `t.pqNullTime = newTime` supposed to work? `pqNullTime` is not a field of `Datetime` and the `NullTime` field that's actually on it is of a different type than that of `newTime`.